# Issue with strings in a MYSQL dynamic query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamicquery

So in short, this should be simple...I have a static query, that I'm trying to re-create dynamically, however it always produces a syntax error. The confusing thing is that if I copy-past the select @statement output it runs fine in MYSQL Workbench.

Below I split the procedure up into 2 separate execute statements, where it appears the second one causes the error, however I think this could be misleading (I'll explain why below).

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_calc_place_win_per`(

IN var_event_type_id int,
IN var_country varchar(45),
IN var_max_bsp float,
IN var_market_type varchar(45),
IN var_increment float,
IN var_first_increment float

)
BEGIN

drop temporary table if exists tbl_results;

if var_market_type = 'win' then
    set @market_type = var_market_type;
    set @rank = 1;
    set @number_of_winners = 1;
else
    set @market_type = var_market_type;
    set @rank = 2;
    set @number_of_winners = 2;
end if;

-- set @a = 'create temporary table tbl_results';
set @b = concat('create temporary table tbl_results select count(case when bsp between 0 and ', var_first_increment, ' then bsp end) as `0-', convert(var_first_increment,char),'` ');
set @statement = @b; -- concat(@a, @b);
set @start_range = round(var_first_increment + 0.01,2);
REPEAT
    set @end_range = round(round(@start_range + var_increment - 0.01,2),2);
    if @end_range > var_max_bsp - var_increment then
        set @end_range = var_max_bsp;   
    end if;
    set @c = concat(', count(case when bsp between ', round(@start_range,2),' and ', round(@end_range,2), ' then bsp end) as `',convert(@start_range,char),'-', convert(round(@end_range,2),char), '` ');
    set @statement = concat(@statement,@c);
    set @start_range = round(@end_range + 0.01,2);

UNTIL @end_range = var_max_bsp
END REPEAT;
set @d = concat(', count(case when bsp > ', round(@end_range,2), ' then bsp end) as `>', convert(round(@end_range,2),char), '` ');
set @e = concat(', winner FROM tbl_betfair_historic_data where event_id in (select event_id from tbl_betfair_historic_data where rank <=', @rank, ' and market_type ="', @market_type , '" and number_of_winners = ' , @number_of_winners, ' and bsp <=' , var_max_bsp , ' and country_code = "', var_country, '" and event_type_id = ', var_event_type_id, ' group by event_id) group by event_id, winner; ');
set @statement = concat(@statement, @d, @e);
prepare st1 from @statement;
execute st1;

-- This is purely in to test the first section produces the results as expected
select * from tbl_results;

-- This section dynamically creates n variables, depending on the var_max_bsp and var_increment variables
set @bsp = 0;
set @total_count = 0;
set @statement = concat(' set @total_', @total_count, ' = (select sum(b.`', @bsp, '-' , var_first_increment,'`) from tbl_results b);');
set @start_range = var_first_increment + 0.01;
REPEAT
set @total_count = @total_count + 1;
set @end_range = @start_range + var_increment - 0.01;   

if @end_range > var_max_bsp - var_increment then
    set @end_range = var_max_bsp;   
end if;

set @s= concat(' set @total_', convert(@total_count,char), ' = (select sum(b.`', convert(round(@start_range,2),char), '-' , convert(round(@end_range,2),char),'`) from tbl_results b);');
set @statement = concat(@statement, @s);
set @start_range = @end_range + 0.01;
UNTIL @end_range = var_max_bsp
END REPEAT;
set @final_total = concat(' set @total_', convert(@total_count+1,char), ' = (select sum(b.`>', convert(round(@end_range,2),char),'`) from tbl_results b); ');
set @statement = concat(@statement, @final_total);
select @statement;
prepare st1 from @statement;
execute st1;

-- This is what the dynamic query should create
/*
set @total_0 = (select 
sum(a.`0-1.4`)
from tbl_results a);

set @total_141 = (select
sum(a.`1.41-1.6`)
from tbl_results a);

set @total_161 = (select
sum(a.`1.61-1.83`)
from tbl_results a);

set @total_183 = (select 
sum(a.`>1.83`)
from tbl_results a);

--This would then be the final section, below is the hard-coded version

select
sum(a.`0-1.4`)/@total_0 as '0-1.4', 
sum(a.`1.41-1.6`)/@total_141  as '1.41-1.6', 
sum(a.`1.61-1.83`)/@total_161 as '1.61-1.83', 
sum(a.`>1.83`)/@total_183 as '>1.83',
if (winner=1,'winner','loser') as 'winner'
from tbl_results a
group by winner;

*/
drop temporary table if exists tbl_results;

END
```

If I run that, then it creates the temp table tbl_results, so it would appear the first section does work, but then I get:

```
14:36:31    call sp_calc_place_win_per(4339, 'GB', 1.83, 'place', 0.2, 1.4) Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @total_1 = (select sum(b.`1.41-1.60`) from tbl_results b); set @total_2 = (s' at line 1
```

However if I copy past the code into Workbench it works fine.

If I concatenate the 2 @statements and run as one, then this is the SQL it generates (which produces the same error):

```
'create temporary table tbl_results select count(case when bsp between 0 and 1.4 then bsp end) as `0-1.4` , count(case when bsp between 1.41 and 1.60 then bsp end) as `1.41-1.60` , count(case when bsp between 1.61 and 1.83 then bsp end) as `1.61-1.83` , count(case when bsp > 1.83 then bsp end) as `>1.83` , winner FROM tbl_betfair_historic_data where event_id in (select event_id from tbl_betfair_historic_data where rank <=2 and market_type =\"place\" and number_of_winners = 2 and bsp <=1.83 and country_code = \"GB\" and event_type_id = 4339 group by event_id) group by event_id, winner;  set @total_0 = (select sum(b.`0-1.4`) from tbl_results b); set @total_1 = (select sum(b.`1.41-1.60`) from tbl_results b); set @total_2 = (select sum(b.`1.61-1.83`) from tbl_results b); set @total_3 = (select sum(b.`>1.83`) from tbl_results b); '
```

So I did wonder if perhaps the strings are causing the problem (i.e. the country_code = and market_type =) as the "GB" obviously doesn't work from MYSQL workbench, yet if I re-format those strings the whole thing works (just in Workbench).

I've tried various ways to re-format the strings with no luck, but also I'm not 100% convinced thats the issue, given I can verify if I keep the code as posted (i.e. with 2 x @statement being executed) then from the select * from tbl_results I can verify it does create that table).

Hopefully that is enough info, but if some parts don't make sense please let me know and I will try to expand.

I'm completely stuck here, so any help is greatly appreciated (oh and apologies for the lack of line breaks, that is because one previous similar question on this topic suggested line breaks can cause issues with dynamic MYSQL stored procedures)!

[UPDATE] as we can be confident now the issue lies with 'part 2' of my code, I created a separate procedure for the first part, but also have included the creation of a dummy temp table, so that it may be easier for people to replicate the error I am seeing:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_calc_place_win_per`(

IN var_event_type_id int,
IN var_country varchar(45),
IN var_max_bsp float,
IN var_market_type varchar(45),
IN var_increment float,
IN var_first_increment float

)
BEGIN

drop temporary table if exists tbl_results;

set @event_type_id = var_event_type_id;
set @country = var_country;
set @max_bsp = var_max_bsp;
set @market_type = var_market_type;
set @increment = var_increment;
set @first_increment = var_first_increment;

/*
prepare create_results_table from 'CALL sp_create_results_table(?,?,?,?,?,?)';
execute create_results_table using 
@event_type_id, @country, @max_bsp, 
@market_type, @increment, @first_increment;*/

-- Create Dummy tbl_results for testing

create temporary table tbl_results
(`0-1.40` float NOT NULL,
`1.41-1.60` float NOT NULL,
`1.61-1.83` float NOT NULL,
`>1.83` float NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_results
(`0-1.40`,
`1.41-1.60`,
`1.61-1.83`,
`>1.83`)
VALUES (7, 5, 3, 2);

set @bsp = 0;
set @total_count = 0;
set @statement = concat(' select sum(tbl_results.`', @bsp, '-' , var_first_increment,'`) into @total_', @total_count,
 ' from tbl_results;');
set @start_range = var_first_increment + 0.01;
REPEAT
set @total_count = @total_count + 1;
set @end_range = @start_range + var_increment - 0.01;   

if @end_range > var_max_bsp - var_increment then
    set @end_range = var_max_bsp;   
end if;

set @s= concat(' select sum(tbl_results.`', convert(round(@start_range,2),char), '-' , 
convert(round(@end_range,2),char),'`) into @total_', convert(@total_count,char), ' from tbl_results;');
set @statement = concat(@statement, @s);
set @start_range = @end_range + 0.01;
UNTIL @end_range = var_max_bsp
END REPEAT;

set @final_total = concat(' select sum(tbl_results.`>', convert(round(@end_range,2),char),'`) into @total_', 
convert(@total_count+1,char), ' from tbl_results; ');
set @statement = concat(@statement, ' ', @final_total);
SELECT @statement;
prepare st1 from @statement;
execute st1;

/*

set @total_0 = (select 
sum(a.`0-1.4`)
from tbl_results a);

set @total_141 = (select
sum(a.`1.41-1.6`)
from tbl_results a);

set @total_161 = (select
sum(a.`1.61-1.83`)
from tbl_results a);

set @total_183 = (select 
sum(a.`>1.83`)
from tbl_results a);

select
sum(a.`0-1.4`)/@total_0 as '0-1.4', 
sum(a.`1.41-1.6`)/@total_141  as '1.41-1.6', 
sum(a.`1.61-1.83`)/@total_161 as '1.61-1.83', 
sum(a.`>1.83`)/@total_183 as '>1.83',
if (winner=1,'winner','loser') as 'winner'
from tbl_results a
group by winner;

select @statement;
*/
drop temporary table if exists tbl_results;
```

Comment: Use `SELECT .. INTO` instead of `SET ..`.

Comment: I tried changing the following as you suggested:

`select sum(b.`0-1.4`) into @total_0 from tbl_results b; 
select sum(b.`1.41-1.60`) into @total_1 from tbl_results b; 
select sum(b.`1.61-1.83`) into @total_2 from tbl_results b; 
select sum(b.`>1.83`) into @total_3 from tbl_results b;`

and as before it works fine in MYSQL workbench, however I get the same syntax error when running as a stored procedure (which seems crazy as it clearly isn't incorrect)!

Comment: I've  updated the question, replacing the initial section of code with a dummy temp table, so that it should be easier to replicate the error I am getting (note: I still am able to run this without error in Workbench, so its something I'm not getting specifically about stored procedures).

Comment: Ah @Akina I think I just realised you meant a single select into!!

That works, I suspect although my approach should theoretically work, it must be that bug where you can't reference the same temp table multiple times in a stored procedure. Also your way is more efficient anyway!